# How I can apply white color for Material UI Icon?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, icons

I need to white Pencil icon, I do:

```
  <CreateIcon style={{ color: white[500] }} />
```

But "white" not exist in Material UI https://material-ui.com/customization/color/#official-color-tool

How I can used white color?

Comment: Not use css properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest couple of ways are:

1)

```
<CreateIcon style={{ color: '#fff' }} />
```

or

2)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  white: {
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
}
```

In your component:

```
const classes = useStyles();
..
<CreateIcon className={classes.white}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override style

```
const WhiteCreateIcon = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: "white"
  }
})(CreateIcon);
```

Codesandbox demo

[image: Edit gallant-feynman-wiirn]

Answer (score 1):

As you may already know, white only has one color (`#fff`). If you want to have different 'shade' of white, you can use grey if that's what you mean.

```
import grey from '@material-ui/core/colors/grey';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  white: {
    color: grey[50],
  },
}

render() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  ...
  return <CreateIcon className={classes.white}/>;
}
```